# File format problem, libreoffice writer is odt format, but i need .pdf, .doc, .docx, .rtf and .txt files format

Tags: libreoffice, file-format

i need writer formats .pdf, .doc, .docx, .rtf and .txt files only. But in ubuntu 14.04 there is Libreoffice writer that comes with ODT format. So, I am not able to upload my resume in ODT format on online portal likes:- shine.com, Naukri.com, etc.

---

1. Need file format .pdf, .doc, .docx, .rtf and .txt files only to
   upload resume

*On online portal they do not accept documents in ODT format by libraoffice writer, so i am looking for word writer which comes with .pdf, .doc, .docx, .rtf and .txt files format.*

Comment: File menu, save as.

Answer (score 8):

Open the ODT file, you can then go to File > Save As (or 'Save as copy'), you can save to those formats and others:

[image]

You can also use 'Export to' and 'Export to PDF' to export to PDF and other formats.

For more information, you can use Help > 'libreoffice help' (or just press <kbd>F1</kbd>) - or use the online help (e.g. [Save As](https://help.libreoffice.org/Common/Save_As), [Export](https://help.libreoffice.org/Common/Export), [Export PDF](https://help.libreoffice.org/Common/Export_as_PDF))

You can also use a command in terminal or a script to convert documents with libreoffice:

```
libreoffice --headless --convert-to <FORMAT> /<path>/<to>/<file>
```

where

- `libreoffice` is the command for libreoffice (or probably libreoffice writer in this case) - this probably could be `libreoffice4.2`, `libreoffice-writer`, or `soffice` depending on how libreoffice was installed
- `--headless` means it won't launch the libreoffice GUI.
- `--convert-to <FORMAT>` - where `<FORMAT>` is the format you want to convert to, like `pdf`, `docx` etc
- `/<path>/<to>/<file>` - file to convert - e.g. `~/Desktop/Untitled\ 1.odt` or `"/home/wilf/Desktop/Untitled 1.odt"`.

For more info on this run `libreoffice --help` or `man libreoffice`.

Comment: See, If have saved a file in ODT file format, than how can i convert that file into different formats. I don't want to write all the topic again, i have written in odt for mat but i want to change the formats to .pdf, .doc, .docx, .rtf and .txt files format

Comment: @NavneetSingh Just open your ODT file and then do what is written in the answer.

Answer (score 3):

You can save documents in LibreOffice in any of listed formats.

Just go to File->Save As...

Also there is a button in toolbar "Save to pdf".

If you already saved a file to odt, you can open it and save in any of the formats you wish.

Comment: Thanks.  See, If have saved a file in ODT file format, than how can i convert that file into different formats. I don't want to write all the topic again, i have written in odt for mat but i want to change the formats to .pdf, .doc, .docx, .rtf and .txt files format

Comment: Just open that file and save it as a file in any of the formats you like. Or just press "export to pdf" button. @NavneetSingh You will see menu If you lift cursor to the top of the screen.

Comment: @NavneetSingh - if this answer helps you can mark it as answered using the tick next to it

Answer (score -1):

You could use office online, a service Microsoft provides. You can use word, excel etc.

[Microsoft Office Online](https://home.office.com)

You will need a Microsoft account

[how to set up a Microsoft account](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-GB/windows-live/sign-up-create-account-how)

Comment: I think you need a valid office 365 account thing to use this...

Comment: @Wilf I have updated my answer

Comment: Down votes? Really? Anyone care to explain why?